# Geodesic polygons in Nokia HERE 3.0?

Tags: javascript, polygon, geospatial, here-api

Using the HERE JavaScript API 3.0, is it possible to create geodesic polygons? I.e. draw the shortest path on the actual earth instead of the plain projection.

Apparently I wasn't able to find anything in the HERE API documentation.

For GoogleMaps this is possible as seen here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geometry-headings?csw=1

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although not available out of the box, It can be implemented using some simple coding. You will find an example here

https://tcs.ext.here.com/examples/v3/geodesic_polyline